# Java RMI ClassCast exception

Tags: java, rmi

I am developing a distributed system using a following JAVA RMI setup.

```
public interface NodeOperations {
 /* RMI methods */
 public FingerTable getFingerTable() throws RMIException;
}

public class Node implements NodeOperations {
 /* Implements all RMI methods */
 /* Also holds a object of FingerTable */
 FingerTable ft;

}

public class FingerTable {
 /* Holds a reference to Node class which has object of 'this' FingerTable */
 Node self;
}
```

All RMI communication is done via methods present in `NodeOperations` interface. There is one method which returns `FingerTable` object for a particular node. However I am getting below exception when I call that method from the client. How do I solve this issue?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5 to field chord.FingerTable.self of type chord.Node in instance of chord.FingerTable
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2237)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:326)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:175)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getNodeInfo(Unknown Source)
    at chord.NodeTest.testTopology(NodeTest.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: Even I thought so but I have made all those classes Serializable.

Comment: This code does not produce this exception. At least two things are missing. Post the real code.

Answer (score 1):

1. If `Node` is intended to be a remote object:

   - `NodeOperations` should extend `Remote`.
   - `Node` should extend `UnicastRemoteObject` or be exported via `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()`.
   - `NodeOperations.getFingerTable()` should be declared to throw `RemoteException`.
   - You should not have a field of type `Node`: it should be of type `NodeOperations`.

   According to the exception, `Node` *already is* an exported remote object. So this isn't the real code.
2. Otherwise, i.e. if you don't want `Node` to be a remote object, `Node` should implement `Serializable`, declare a `serialVersionUID` member, etc.
3. Your class definitions seem rather circular. Review them.